# Reset Auto_Increment Value After Data Delete MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table automatically increments id if a value has been added to the name column. This works fine (left table) unless I remove a row and insert another (right table). Here, the auto_increment counts id from the last point it remembered.

How can I achieve the auto_increment to count ID according to amount of rows in table instead of remembering initial value. Thanks in advance.

```
+----+------+  +----+------+ 
| id | name |  | id | name |
+----+------+  +----+------+
|  1 | Bob  |  |  1 | Bob  |
|  2 | Mary |  |  2 | Mary |
|  3 | Jane |  |  3 | Jane |
|  4 | Jade |  |  5 | Leo  |   
+----+------+  +----+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to achieve this in some programming language. If thats the case then for example if its php. You can find the most recent row and find the id of it and add + 1 to it. And have it incremented. But i dont recommend doing that for auto increment field. If you want to have a sequential id for a given table. Simply have the id as integer and not auto increment. And always update the id column when you insert some data and update the id when you have to. Its as simple as doing +1.

Please let me know what are you trying to achieve I might help you and fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Yeah, I have a site where I add and remove some values using PHP. Thanks for directing me, I am going to implement what you suggested.